# How to match multiple tokens using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, boost-regex

I need using regular expressions to match special key and values. There is a special condition that I do not know how to do.

The string likes `abcd/abcd`. I need match all single words before `/`.
So I write `(.)*/`, and then I found it only match 1 token (d). What's more, even it matches all I need, I still do not know how many tokens matched.

So what should the correct regular expressions be? The real condition is much more complex than the example, so if it can be achieved by regular expressions, I do not want write a tokenizer.

Comment: [`(.*?)\/`](https://regex101.com/r/hB1gD9/2) OR [`^([^\/]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/hB1gD9/3)

Comment: Please post the real string. What is the language?

Comment: @Tushar My fault. I make mistake, it only matches `abcd` at once. I need match `a` `b` `c` `d`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Match the special string multi times using `()` is my purpose.

Comment: Besides the language, what is the real pattern you have?

Comment: If it is .NET, you can use your `(.)*` and grab the values from the CaptureCollection. Same can be done in Python with PyPi regex module. And with Boost, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you show me reference of boost about CaptureCollection? I think that's what I need.

Comment: Check http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/regex/doc/captures.html

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's it! Plz post your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Boost library that you are using provides a way to capture repeated groups into a *stack* *provided* you compiled the library with `BOOST_REGEX_MATCH_EXTRA` flag set, otherwise `what` won't have a member named `captures`. When you use `boost::regex_search` or `boost::regex_match`, pass the `boost::match_extra` flag, and you will capture all vlaues with your `(.)*` (matching and capturing any character but a newline, zero or more occurrences) into a stack that is acessible via the `captures` member of the `sub_match` object.

Here is a demo method from the [official Boost site](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/regex/doc/captures.html):

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>


void print_captures(const std::string& regx, const std::string& text)
{
   boost::regex e(regx);
   boost::smatch what;
   std::cout << "Expression:  \"" << regx << "\"\n";
   std::cout << "Text:        \"" << text << "\"\n";
   if(boost::regex_match(text, what, e, boost::match_extra))
   {
      unsigned i, j;
      std::cout << "** Match found **\n   Sub-Expressions:\n";
      for(i = 0; i < what.size(); ++i)
         std::cout << "      $" << i << " = \"" << what[i] << "\"\n";
      std::cout << "   Captures:\n";
      for(i = 0; i < what.size(); ++i)
      {
         std::cout << "      $" << i << " = {";
         for(j = 0; j < what.captures(i).size(); ++j)
         {
            if(j)
               std::cout << ", ";
            else
               std::cout << " ";
            std::cout << "\"" << what.captures(i)[j] << "\"";
         }
         std::cout << " }\n";
      }
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "** No Match found **\n";
   }
}

int main(int , char* [])
{
   print_captures("(.*)bar|(.*)bah", "abcbar");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Notice: Compile the regex library with `BOOST_REGEX_MATCH_EXTRA` set, otherwise `what` has no member named `captures`.

Answer (score 2):

**Why your regex doesn't work**

The regex `(.)*/` matches any character, zero or more times, followed by a `/`.

The `*` quantifier is *greedy*, it'll try to match whatever it can. Given the string "abcd/abcd", the regex engine matches "abcd/abcd", then it fails to match "/", so it backtracks until it reaches the "d", and finally make one step and matches the "/". The `()` is a group, and you're catching only the last character.

**How to fix it**

```
[^\/]*
```

This matches anything that's *not* a "/" (note that it's escaped), and is exactly what you want. If you want to catch the matched regex, you should change it to `([^\/]*)`, and now the first group contains your regex.

Note that there could be many solutions depending on the language you're using, not necessarily regex ones.

Comment: Thanks for clear answer, but I do not want to match all the four characters. I need got four groups `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.

Comment: `([^\/]*)` will match the whole sequence before the "/".

Comment: Yes, so what I need is match single char four times and gives me four groups.

Comment: @zzy `(.)(.)(.)(.)\/`

Comment: @zzy Then the best solution would be catch the whole group and iterate on it manually, depending on the programming language you're using.